# how show app correctly in recent task in android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

How show app when it app finished and the user clicked in recent task, my app don't show correctly, this show other screen, in this App, i use animation when transtion activity and it app is finish this execute finishedAfterTransition in exist in Android 5.0.

here is a image the App when show in recent task:

[image]

Comment: do you want to remove ur app (EL Uni) from cerrar TODO? once it finished?

Comment: It seems that the guy is having problems with his app displaying correctly when he views "recent apps"/square button. Although I don't know the answer it could be because of the animation is not done properly or as suggested your intents are messed up. Try creating a blank new app, with some lorem ipsum and if that works then switch to your app and slowly try to work out what part of your app is messed up. I assume you restarted your phone in case Android is bugged, had this once on some built in Google apps.

Answer (score 1):

maybe your intents did not finish correctly.Check them

if you want to remove it from resent tasks ..
different ways to approach

use

```
finishAndRemoveTask();
```

when user exits it.

for the activity in manifest file

```
  android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

Comment: thanks, I don´t function correctly, it`s happen other problems when implemented your code, thanks very much